# javascript select alphabetically sorting

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to sort option alphabetically

My Html is

```
<select id="myOpt">
    <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
    <option value="3">John Snow</option>
    <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
    <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
    <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```

js

```
var options = $("#myOpt option");                           
options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {               
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();         
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);            
});
options.appendTo("#myOpt");
```

it sorts option correctly but now instead of selected option it shows last option. My question is how to show selected option instead of last option and can it be done by another client side method? since for big list it making page slow

Comment: Hello @Richerd Can you please add the code of html after sorting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```js
var options = $("#myOpt option");  
var selectedVal = '';                         
options.detach().sort(function(a,b) {               
    var at = $(a).text();
    var bt = $(b).text();   
    if($(a).attr('selected') || $(b).attr('selected')){
        selectedVal = $(a).attr('selected') ? $(a).val() : $(b).val();
        return false;    
    }
    return (at > bt)?1:((at < bt)?-1:0);            
});
options.appendTo("#myOpt");
$('#myOpt').val(selectedVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myOpt">
    <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
    <option value="3">John Snow</option>
    <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
    <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
    <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't select the 1st option to sort. var options = $("#myOpt option:not(:eq(0))");

You may use web workers to avoid browser frize if this a big list.
also, you can put it inside setTimeout to push it in event loop

```js
$(function() {
  var options = $("#myOpt option:not(:eq(0))");
  options.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    var be = $(b);
    var ae = $(a);

    if (be.attr('selected')) {
      selectedVal = be.val();
      return 1;
    }
    if (ae.attr('selected')) {
      selectedVal = ae.val();
      return -1;
    }

    var at = ae.text();
    var bt = be.text();
    return (at > bt) ? 1 : ((at < bt) ? -1 : 0);
  });
  options.appendTo("#myOpt");
  $("#myOpt").val(selectedVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myOpt">
  <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
  <option value="3">John Snow</option>
  <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
  <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
  <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var options = $("#myOpt option");
  options.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    var be = $(b);
    var ae = $(a);

    if (be.attr('selected')) {
      selectedVal = be.val();
      return 1;
    }
    if (ae.attr('selected')) {
      selectedVal = ae.val();
      return -1;
    }

    var at = ae.text();
    var bt = be.text();
    return (at > bt) ? 1 : ((at < bt) ? -1 : 0);
  });
  options.appendTo("#myOpt");
  $("#myOpt").val(selectedVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myOpt">
  <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
  <option value="3">John Snow</option>
  <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
  <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
  <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what if a option has a different selected value ? is there any option to show selected option by "SELECTED" tag instead ?

Answer (score 1):

To do the sort using native JavaScript may actually give you somewhat more readable code, while taking advantage of operations (like `shift/unshift`) that jQuery does not implement.

The selection issue is occurring because an `option` detached from it's `parent` select cannot be selected - so you need to either select the first option again.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var options = $("#myOpt option").detach()
    options = $.makeArray(options);
    var first = options.shift();
    options.sort( (a,b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text) );
    options.unshift(first);
    $("#myOpt").append(options);
    $("#myOpt option").eq(0).prop("selected", true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myOpt">
    <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
    <option value="3">John Snow</option>
    <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
    <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
    <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```

You may want to simply just leave the selected element alone and just detach/sort the others, which ends up being quite a bit simpler:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var options = $("#myOpt option").not('[value=""]').detach();
    options.sort( (a,b) => a.text.localeCompare(b.text) );
    $("#myOpt").append(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myOpt">
    <option value="" selected data-default>Select Name</option>
    <option value="3">John Snow</option>
    <option value="34">Arya Stark</option>
    <option value="54">Sansa Stark</option>
    <option value="4">Hound</option>
</select>
```